# P4Python Perforce API does not honor P4_TRUST when running as a Collectd Python (2.7) Plugin

Tags: python-2.7, perforce, collectd

Using Collectd Python Plugin to collect Graphite Metrics from Perforce using their P4Python API.  All is good with the exception of ssl based connections which require a P4_TRUST command to assert the fingerprint for the given server prior to the login() command.

Specifically:

```
import collectd
from P4 import P4

def configer(configobj):
    collectd.info('Configuring Perforce Plugin')


def initer():
    collectd.info('Initializing Perforce Plugin')


def reader():
    p4 = P4()
    p4.port = "ssl:perforce1.lab.dell.com:1666"
    p4.user = "perforce"
    p4.charset = 'utf8'
    p4.password = "Password"
    p4.connect()
    p4.run_trust("-i", '60:27:3E:E0:A6:58:8E:13:4F:9E:8C:C8:BF:C3:26:C2:91:2F:78:33')
    p4.run_login()

    result = p4.run('license', '-u')
    collectd.info("User limit is :" + result[0].get('userLimit'))

#
    p4.disconnect()

# -- Hook Callbacks, Order is important! ==#
collectd.register_config(configer)
collectd.register_init(initer)
collectd.register_read(reader)
```

will result in the following run time errors noted in collectd.log

```
`[2017-04-27 11:33:58] Unhandled python exception in read callback: P4Exception: [P4#run] Errors during command execution( "p4 login" )

    [Error]: "The authenticity of '10.99.248.42:1666' can't be established,\nthis may be your first attempt to connect to this P4PORT.\nThe fingerprint for the key sent to your client is\n60:27:3E:E0:A6:58:8E:13:4F:9E:8C:C8:BF:C3:26:C2:91:2F:78:33\nTo allow connection use the 'p4 trust' command."


[2017-04-27 11:33:58] read-function of plugin `python.PerforceMetrics' failed. Will suspend it for 20.000 seconds.
`
```

The same code run outside the collectd context runs as expected.

```
from P4 import P4
import logging

FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s: %(name)s: %(levelname)s :  %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, filename='/var/log/pytest.log', level=logging.INFO)

def reader():
    p4 = P4()
    p4.port = "ssl:perforce1.cec.lab.emc.com:1666"
    p4.user = "perforce"
    p4.charset = 'utf8'
    p4.password = "Password"
    p4.connect()
    p4.run_trust("-i", '80:25:3E:E0:A6:58:8E:13:4F:9E:8C:C8:BF:C3:26:C2:91:2F:78:33')
    p4.run_login()

    result = p4.run('license', '-u')
    logging.info ("User limit is :" + result[0].get('userLimit'))

    #
    p4.disconnect()

reader()
```

NOTE:  None SSL connections that do not require "P4 Trust" work correctly under collectd.

Any clues, idea's or how to approach this?

Comment: Are you sure that your 'p4.run_trust' command is working? Have you looked in your ~/.p4trust file to verify that it contains the information you expected, compared to how it looks when you run 'p4 trust' from the command line?

Comment: Bryan,  yep I'm sure the p4 trust is running correctly ... Note: the second code set without the collectd ... this works fine.  As a matter of fact when I run my code from PyCharm even with the collectd python lib loaded it executes correctly ... it just fails and throws the trust error when the Python plugin is loaded by the Collectd daemon.  BTW ... using p4python API does not make use of the .p4trust file ... instead you specify the finger print directly `p4.run_trust("-i", '80:25:3E:E0:A6:58:8E:13:4F:9E:8C:C8:BF:C3:26:C2:91:2F:78:33')`

Answer (score 0):

Okay so worked with Perforce support and while they struggled with getting collectd running they did point me in the right direction.  Specifically P4TRUST as an environment variable can be defined that points to the .p4trust file that is typically used and by default created with the application of the p4.run_trust p4Python API call.
So the trick is to define the environment P4TRUST environment variable with in your python plugin:

```
import collectd
import os
from P4 import P4

def configer(configobj):
    collectd.info('Configuring Perforce Plugin')


def initer():
    collectd.info('Initializing Perforce Plugin')


def reader():
    os.environ["P4TRUST"]="/root/.p4trust"
    p4 = P4()
    p4.port = "ssl:perforce1.lab.dell.com:1666"
    p4.user = "perforce"
    p4.charset = 'utf8'
    p4.password = "Password"
    p4.connect()
    p4.run_trust("-i", '60:27:3E:E0:A6:58:8E:13:4F:9E:8C:C8:BF:C3:26:C2:91:2F:78:33')
    p4.run_login()

result = p4.run('license', '-u')
collectd.info("User limit is :" + result[0].get('userLimit'))

#
p4.disconnect()

# -- Hook Callbacks, Order is important! ==#
collectd.register_config(configer)
collectd.register_init(initer)
collectd.register_read(reader)
```

Note: the inclusion of the os library and the use of

os.environ["P4TRUST"]="/root/.p4trust"

That's the ticker!